Why disks might be special - on chords that cut off segments of a specified area from a planar convex body
This post presents a variant of On segments of equal area cut from planar convex regions by chords
Consider a planar convex region C of unit area and all chords of it that cut off a segment of area α from C.
Question: Is there any unit area C
other than the circular disk with the property: for even any one value of the fraction α, all chords that break off segments of area α from C have same length?
And is there any C other than the circular disk with the property:  even for one length l, all chords of length l break off segments of equal area from C?
Note: There are other variants of the question with 'perimeter', 'moment of inertia' etc replacing 'area' in 2D and also analogs in 3D.
